# Entity Framework: How do I delete table rows that reference each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I delete the order without getting this exception?

`UserLicenses` references `SerialOnOrderDetails` and vice-versa:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_SerialsOnOrderDetail_UserLicenses". The conflict occurred in database "sales", table "dbo.SerialsOnOrderDetail", column 'UserLicenseId'.

Delete confirmed controller action code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]    
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Order order = GetOrderById(id);

    if (order.UserLicenses.Count > 0)
    {
        context.UserLicenses.RemoveRange(order.UserLicenses);
    }

    if (order.SerialsOnOrderDetails.Count > 0)
    {
        context.SerialsOnOrderDetails.RemoveRange(order.SerialsOnOrderDetails);
    }

    context.Orders.Remove(order);

    context.SaveChanges(); // Exception here !!!
}
```

**[EDIT] Added live data**

Live data (Id = UserLicenseId):

[image]

Additional classes:

```
public partial class UserLicense
{   
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string AssignedUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SerialsOnOrderDetail> SerialsOnOrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class SerialsOnOrderDetail
{
   public int orderID { get; set; }
   public string serial { get; set; }
   public string productID { get; set; }
   public string UserLicenseId { get; set; }
   public int customerID { get; set; }

   public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
   public virtual Serial Serial1 { get; set; }
   public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
   public virtual UserLicense UserLicense { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
        this.SerialsOnOrderDetails = new HashSet<SerialsOnOrderDetail>();
        this.UserLicenses = new HashSet<UserLicense>();
    }

    public int orderID { get; set; }
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public string promoCodeID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> resellerID { get; set; }
    public string invoiceID { get; set; }
    public string poNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> paymentDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> validated { get; set; }
    public string resellerOrderID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> parentOrderID { get; set; }
    public int months { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual PromoCode PromoCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Reseller Reseller { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SerialsOnOrderDetail> SerialsOnOrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Order ParentOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLicense> UserLicenses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't affected by the IDE you use, so the `[visual-studio]` tag is irrelevant here. Please only use the `[visual-studio]` tag for questions about using Visual Studio (as indicated by [its tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info)).

Comment: How did you insert these rows in the first place? One of them had to have been inserted first before the other row even existed, so could not have been referencing it at that time. Whatever mechanism/ordering applied during the inserts, perform the same steps in reverse during deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you verify if UserLicenses and SerialsOnOrderDetails collections are properly loaded and not empty ? Are you sure removerange is the proper way to do it ? I suggest you to read a few tutorials about EF if you are not used to it.

Maybe you'll have to update GetOrderById with .Include("....") directives to load these collections, or load the related items manually.

Comment: Yes, `UserLicenses` collection contains 2 items while `SerialsOnOrderDetails` 4 items. I suspect that the error is connected to DB constraints instead.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the EF. Did you tried in pure SQL to see exactly the affected rows and if the UserLicense to delete is not used in another SerialsOnOrderDetail (for example) ? It would explain the constraint violation.

Comment: I've just edited OP to add live data, does it help to understand the problem?

Comment: And did you verify if none of these user licenses is used in another SerialsOnOrderDetails  record ? Your screenshot does not tell it as it's focused on the Order and not the rows to delete themselves. 
Also, as already suggested, try to run the delete in pure sql (in a transaction with ROLLBACK at the end if you don't want to actually remove the rows).

Comment: Yes, the UserLicenseId `gx2rdtch` is used also in order `104458`. This explains the error in records removal.

Comment: So I was right about foreign key violation and this has nothing to do with EF ? Glad to see you have fixed your problem !

Answer (score 0):

That constraint message you quote is from the underlying SQL Server. It's not an EF error as such, it's passed through.

When I get this sort of problem in TSQL the solution is generally to delete both of the mutually referencing rows in a single transaction.

While I'm not terribly familiar with EF, a quick search turn up this example of putting multiple operations into a single transactional context instead of the default behaviour of a single transaction per operation.

```
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
    using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            Author author1 = new Author() {    Name = "Mark" };
            Author author2 = new Author() {    Name = "John" };
            
            context.Authors.Add(author1);
            context.SaveChanges();
            
            context.Authors.Add(author2);
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

I notice another respondent describes other things that could be wrong. It is entirely possible that we are both right and there are multiple issues to resolve.

Comment: No, even adding multiple `context.SaveChanges()` calls does not help, sorry.

Comment: You can only delete both rows at the same time if they're stored in the same table. Otherwise, it's no help because SQL Server doesn't support deferred checks on foreign keys (which, in other products, would allow the check to only occur when the transaction is committed). You have to have two statements affecting the two tables and the error will occur with the first statement.